# Can "You, too" be a negative short reply to a negative command, if you want to tell him not to do what he has just wanted you not to

Tags: grammar, meaning, negation, imperative-sentences

Suppose there are two people. One of them tells the other to do something and the other wants the other person to do the same. So, A tells B **"Eat an apple"**, B wants A to do the same thing.

So, B can shortly tell  **"you, too".**, which means "I want you to do same thing." or **"you must do the same as what you told me to."** For instance:

**"A: Eat an apple."**

**"B: You, too."**

So far so good. The answer of B **"You, too"** simply gives the same command to A in a shorter form.

My question is what happens if the command is negative. For instance;

**"A: Do not make noise."**

**"B: ................?????"**

So, B wants to respond **"Don't you make a noise either, just like you tell me not to."**

So, Can B use the same above structure **(You, too)** when the impreative is negative? Or must it be in another form like:

**"You either"** or

**"You neither"** or

**"Nor you"**

**"Neither you"**

or none of the above?

Comment: "Don't you, either."

Comment: I'm not understanding. Do you want a response that means "I will eat an apple, but I don't want you to eat an apple," or do you want a response that means "I will not eat an apple, and I don't want you to eat one either."

Comment: There is no short idiomatically established response for the situation being described here. Perhaps partly because ***any*** response would almost certainly call attention to *which of the two conversants is "**dominant**"*. I'm sure speakers of all languages get very careful when using utterances that reflect who's the dominant party and who's the submissive one in ***any*** "conversation", but *particularly, a conversation starting with an imperative, where the addressee wants to **reply** with an imperative*. I find it easier to imagine OP's context if B is a child (not yet "socialised").

Comment: Archetypal example... Dad: "Don't smoke / swear / sleep around / get drunk", Son: "You shouldn't smoke / etc. either!".

Comment: FumbleFingers, thanks for the comment. Are you sure "you should not smoke" will function as strong as a negative command just like "Don't smoke".? It sounds like an advice rather than a command.

Answer (score 2):

In casual speech, it's common to say "You, neither." I suppose this is the equivalent of "You, too". Somewhat more formal would be, "Neither should you" or "You shouldn't either" or "I don't think you should either."

Comment: I might say 'nor you'.

Comment: Kate Bunting's suggestion "Don't you, either", really makes sense. And your answer "Nor you" sounds interesting. So, if B says "Nor you", would it mean  the same as "Don't you, either"?

Comment: @yunus Yes. All these answers mean basically the same thing.